# Sql server Query to Select Isolated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

hi i am using Sql server Query to Select Isolated rows, 
I am giving TicketEsclationID and TicketEsclationSubcategoryID and i want to select connected UserInfoUserID and SeniorUserInfoUserID.

For example if i give UserInfoUserID as 2020 the rest rows should populated

below is the screen shot of same

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please define the expected results given the 3 limits you've asked for. I think you're after a recursive CTE to traverse the hierarchy to get you rows 2,3,4. but I would like to confirm my understanding.

Comment: Paste your data here to turn it into a text table that you can use in your question: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Comment: @xQbert I agree. Looks like get ancestors + get descendants

Comment: @xQbert yes sir you are right

Comment: A simple example: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/

Comment: @SqlZim  yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you are trying to do this?

```
Select top (1) with ties * from yourtable
    order by row_number() over(partition by TicketEsclationId, TicketEsclationSubCategoryId order by SeniorUserInfoUserId desc)
```

Comment: but sir, if i want to start from 2021 and remaining bottom rows, how i can do that ?

Comment: are you looking only to filter 2021?

Comment: no sir, if i give 2020 below as UserInfoUserID row 2020 ,2021 and 2019 should come and if i select UserInfoUserID  as 2021 row 2021 and 2019  and so on should come